# SVG alpha filter altering pixel color

Tags: svg-filters

I'm using JS and `<canvas>` to render an isometric scene. I'm using this SVG filter so that the tiles have sharp pixel edges:

```
<svg width="0" height="0" style="position:absolute;z-index:-1;">
  <defs>
    <filter id="remove-alpha" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
      <feComponentTransfer>
        <feFuncA type="linear" slope="255"></feFuncA>
      </feComponentTransfer>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

This forces any transluscent pixels to render as opaque. But it's also slightly altering the color of the effected pixels, so they are noticeably different from the rest of the tile. I've only just started messing with svg filters, is there a way to modify this so that it doesn't alter the color of the pixels?

[image]

Comment: This is very interesting. What gave you the idea to use SVG for a 3D environment? Is this for a game? It looks really nice so far.

Comment: Thanks! it's not really a 3d environment, just has that effect because of the tile draw ordering. I'm using the SVG filter so that the tile edges don't get anti-aliased when rendered to the canvas, I'm looking for a crisp, pixel-ly feel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some anti-aliasing schemes use rgb values other than the source rgb value (for example - sub-pixel anti-aliasing vs grey-scale antialiasing for font rendering). In these schemes, when you boost the opacity of these pixels - you can end up with a different color.

In pure SVG, you'd use shape-rendering=crispEdges to eliminate anti-aliasing. But Canvas has no option like this.

One solution here - rather than boost the opacity of the anti-aliasing pixels, you could try eliminating them - so only (almost) fully opaque pixels remain. You can do this using a different feComponentTransfer. This filter below sets every opacity below about .96 to 0, and every opacity above that to 1.

```html
<svg width="0" height="0" style="position:absolute;z-index:-1;">
  <defs>
    <filter id="crush-alpha" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
      <feComponentTransfer>
        <feFuncA type="discrete" tableValues="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1></feFuncA>
      </feComponentTransfer>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```